# How can restrict to display the country name in formatted address?

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

In google map auto suggestion shows the formatted address like "Avenue of the Americas, New York, NY, United States".
I am using widgets.js for this action.
Here doesn't need the country name. Is this possible? Yes means how?

```
x = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(s[0], {
    types: ["geocode"]
});
```

this is in widget.js

Comment: Google address results are made up of a number of components: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types

Comment: I have added the code above. where can I change ? If I give anything in types nothing happened